# Service Worker with Next.js /app directory v14

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel

I'm working on a Next.js (v13 or later) project using the `/app` directory architecture. I'd like to implement a service worker to enhance my website's performance and offline capabilities, but I'm having trouble finding resources specifically addressing this setup.

Here's what I need help with:

- **Registration:** How do I correctly register the service worker in my `app/page.js` file?
- **Service Worker Logic:** What's the best approach to write the core service worker code (`service-worker.js`) for caching strategies and potential offline support within the `/app` directory structure?
- **Considerations:** Are there any Next.js-specific considerations or quirks I should be aware of when implementing a service worker in the `/app` directory?

**Things I've tried:**

- I've searched for tutorials and guides, but most seem to focus on older Next.js versions or don't address the `/app` directory.
- I understand the basics of service workers in general, but I'm unsure how to adapt it to Next.js's newer architecture.